# Ubuntu android studio: Invisible widget

Tags: java, android, xml, tensorflow

Good morning. I am a student who wants to use tensor flow on Android.
Maybe this is a very basic problem. 
However, I can not find a solution to this problem.
I'm now configuring the xml view, but my widgets are not showing up on the screen. 
I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I am using Android Studio version 3.0.1.
Also, I am working remotely using MobaXterm. 
The odd thing is that when I run the same XML code in Windows Android Studio, the design looks good.
[image]

Adjusting the Visibility property is no different.

[image]

How do I make it appear on the screen?

Comment: have you restart your android studio? if not,restart and try

Comment: I've restarted it, but I still have the problem.

Comment: I've fixed the issue. I lowered the target api from 28 to 27 and it looked normal.